# Pass output value from AWS batch Jobs in between

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-batch

I have an AWS batch running two jobs using EKS.
When the first job finishes, I want to output the value and pass it to the second Job for execution.
Can I do this from Jobs? or Do I need to save and fetch these values using another AWS service?

My containers are running a Python script and require updated values every time the first job finishes to run the second Job.

Any help will be appreciated.